# How to find out if a PDF file has data not visible within the bounding box?

Tags: pdf, crop, bounding-box, pdfcrop, convert

I am embedding a small area of a large webpage into a document compiled with pdflatex (using `\includegraphics`). A raster image / screenshot produces artifacts when zooming in, so instead I am saving the page as a PDF with the browser's print dialog, and cropping the section I need.

```
$ pdfcrop --margins "-50 -65 -40 -400" full-page.pdf area.pdf
```

This tool changes the bounding box, and produces the desired *visual* appearance. But the file preserves all the content of the original.

```
$ ls -lh *.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 7.1M Apr 27 14:48 area.pdf
-rw------- 1 user group 7.1M Apr 27 14:02 full-page.pdf
```

There is personal information contained outside the bounding box I would like to ensure is not in the cropped pdf (usernames, timestamps, ids, etc.). Given a string of ascii plaintext in the original document, e.g. my username, how would i go about finding whether it's present in the PDF. Can I expect ascii text from the page to be contained literally or would it be encoded in some vectorial form?

I mention that the file is coming from a browser, because intuitively, browsers might encode their printed PDFs in a predictable way, maybe it's easy to clip areas if it maps to the DOM directly.

### pdf2ps experiment

I've converted the pdf to ps and back (pdf2ps, followed by ps2pdf) and that did trim the file size down drastically, but without knowing exactly how to interpret the contents of the file, or knowing what's involved in those conversions, I can't be certain whether the content I want to get rid of is finally gone, hidden, or simply spatially re-optimized /compressed.

```
$ pdf2ps area.pdf && ps2pdf area.ps
$ ls -lh *.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 259K Apr 27 14:59 area.pdf
-rw------- 1 user group 7.1M Apr 27 14:02 full-page.pdf
```

The initial page is mostly fonts and lines, with the exception of a few icons. The fonts however are CJK. Everything in the end looks good at any scale, so it does seem vector paths are preserved via a conversion.

*Edit*: Rephrasing question in light of a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247119/pdfcrop-content-remains?rq=1) about stripping content with pdfcrop (I'd missed it in my search before writing here). I'm more interested in ensuring that some of the text data is *not* in the pdf at this point. I'm asking this community because of familiarity its users have with embedding documents of the sort, as well as with the underlying formats involved.

Comment: Can you save it as `.eps` file? Or convert the .pdf to .eps?

Comment: eps has a concept of bounding boxes too though, no?

Is there some guarantee that data that I can't see visually won't be present in the underlying file? will going to eps and back produce a pdf with 0,0,0,0 bounding box? -- edit (I meant no bounding box)

Comment: You can change the bounding box by hand. However a bounding box of 0,0,0,0 consists of only… 1 point.  You can check the cropping resulting files with `gsview` (on Windows) or `Ghostview` (Linux, and probably Mac OS).

Comment: That won't remove the data though. Just change which portion of it is visible.

Comment: Oh! I see.  Which king of data are there which are not visible, but still in the file?

Comment: In my case it's usernames and timestamps/dates. But it could also be credit card numbers, privacy settings, etc. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Well you may check if they're still there (as they don't appear I really don't see why they should be in the file): an .eps file is a text file. And you write on it if you know the `postscript` language.

Comment: It is pretty hard to do what you ask, consider your cropping bounding box could go half way through a letter  cutting out the clipped part would mean extracting the font data and trying to create paths for the visible part, or consider clipping some spiral drawn via tikz, to generate the paths just of some visible part would be mathematically intractable in most cases. safest way would be to make a high resolution bitmap and clip that. (If it's just text you could OCR the text from the clipped image, perhaps...

Comment: thos is pretty much a duplicate of this pdfcrop question (as the issues affect any cropping tool, not just pdfcrop) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247119/pdfcrop-content-remains?rq=1

Comment: eps is text, but is a program. I'm not super familiar with what can and cannot be clipped. I assume rectangles and lines are easy to clip, fonts may depend, and certain things must be atomic (can't be divided).

I'd be happy with having _some_ guarantee the data's gone. I do feel it requires knowledge about the structure of the pdf -- i.e. how browsers encode the webpages they print.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't try this: https://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/news/whitehall-black-on-black-text-security-blunder/

Comment: What you want is lossy crop. AFAIK only Adobe Acrobat does that. Anyway I think this question is off-topic here; you might have better luck at superuser.sx or graphics.sx