# Regarding pages that are not visible in PDF

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to make a new page such that it's not visible on the PDF but can be searched using the find function?

For ex; you add keywords to a resume that are not visible on the resume itself but are found when searched for in a database of resumes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This would fool resume-scanners from ten or fifteen years ago, but not today. It's also pretty dishonest to try to 'trick' their system. If you don't want to be relegated to the system, give them a phone call or email them. As for your actual question, you can add metadata (*actual* keywords) to the PDF using `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is my personal belief that in a system which has 1000s of resumes, the idea of using a 'hack' (if it works) to get through the first hoop but still going through the rest of the steps of the entire process doesn't seem dishonest to me. I hope that I didn't rub you the wrong way. Thank you for your time

Comment: i am not sure i understand, can you try `\scalebox{0}{invisibles, key, words}%`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367117/how-to-find-out-if-a-pdf-file-has-data-not-visible-within-the-bounding-box) we determined that hidden portions of pdf images are stored in their entirety.  Further experiments have shown that you can search for text in these hidden portions, at least if they are close to the visible portion.

The following creates a pdf image containing keywords.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{\hspace{10pt}}l@{}}% leave left 10pt blank
  first\\
  second\\
  third
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In this document only the blank portion is visible.  And if I search (with Acrobat) it highlights where the keyword would be if it were visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{keywords.pdf}}% determine height
\raisebox{-\ht0}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\includegraphics[clip,viewport=0 0 10pt \ht0]{keywords.pdf}}}%
This is all that is visible.
\end{document}
```