# How to create a PDF with picture upload?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I created a PDF file with a table that the user can fill up, then save (I used the package hyperref with TextField).

Now I would like to be able to do the same thing with a picture, that is, the PDF contains a template of the picture, the user can save the picture, edit it with whatever software he/she likes, then update the PDF with it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Sorry i dont know about something like that. Do you have some code (up to now)? Please see: ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Comment: Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29937&sid=2a4be95646120f8265feb9d48df18fcc

Comment: Here is what I have so far:

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
My Text
\begin{Form}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
  \hline
             & A & B \\
  \hline
  Row 1   & \TextField[name=N1]{} & \TextField[name=N2]{} \\
  \hline
  Row 2   & \TextField[name=N3]{} & \TextField[name=N4]{} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centerline{\includegraphics{MyImage}}
\end{figure}
\end{Form}
\end{document}

Comment: You can put an image into a form, but Acrobat will not recognize it as copyable (only the text inside).  Have you EVER been able to copy an image from a PDF?

Comment: "Have you EVER been able to copy an image from a PDF?"

Yes, I simply right-click on the image, then "save image as". I use Linux's default viewer Evince.

Comment: Interesting!  Would you mind copying the image from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367513/regarding-pages-that-are-not-visible-in-pdf/367550?s=1|0.2703#367550 to see if you get the hidden parts.

Comment: So I created the PDF with the keywords, then the second PDF that includes it as an image. When I open it with Evince, it only shows rectangles and the text "This is all that is visible", no keywords. It doesn't allow me to save it as an image, probably because it is not is not a bitmap image.

Comment: Some approaches regarding how to upload pictures into a PDF form are being discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656276/47927

Answer (score 7):

No, pictures cannot be included by the user via interactive forms. From the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html):

> **12.7.4.1 General**
>
> Interactive forms support the following field types:
>
> - *Button fields* represent interactive controls on the screen that the user can manipulate with the mouse. They include *pushbuttons*,
>     *check boxes*, and *radio buttons*.
> - *Text fields* are boxes or spaces in which the user can enter text from the keyboard.
> - *Choice fields* contain several text items, at most one of which may be selected as the field value. They include *scrollable list boxes*
>     and *combo boxes*.
> - *Signature fields* represent digital signatures and optional data for authenticating the name of the signer and the document's contents.

Pictures based on text would be possible, see [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), for example.
But, bitmaps, PDF images, ... are not supported.

Comment: Isn't there any possible hack by using some JavaScript code?

Comment: There is `app.media`, where a video or something like this can be played, where the media is addressed by a URL. But, I do not know, if there is a "player" for pictures. And, I doubt that this is close to your intentions, because the media will not be embedded.